# Avoid applicationContext.xml in my Action and Service Classes

Tags: spring, struts

I am writing a web application using Struts, Spring framework. 
In the Struts Action I am Injecting Service Classes as follows

```
    ApplicationContext context =
            new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
    loginService = (LoginService)context.getBean("loginService");
```

How can I avoid mentioning applicationContext.xml in my Action classes I just have to use 
loginService = (LoginService)context.getBean("loginService"); without specifying the .xml file in my class.

I came across to use below while googling

private LoginService loginService = (LoginService)ApplicationContextProvider.getContext().getBean("loginService");

But I do not want to use static method getContext().

Answer (score 2):

Spring support Struts integration in the package [org.springframework.web.struts](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/struts/package-summary.html).

Take a look at this [article](http://www.javabeat.net/articles/70-integrating-struts-with-spring-2.html) for an example.